# How to make a bottom navigation bar visible?

Tags: android, android-navigation

[image]

[image]

Navigation bar can be seen in picture 1.But when i develop a app and build it, there is no navigation bar.
Please help me to overcome this problem

Comment: sooo, what have you tried already? Did you Google your problem? If you tried out something, what did you try?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: super.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
,,,
I tried this code but when interrupt another program on this such as messanger , then it didnt work . And one think i want only show the navigation bar not to hide the bar.

Comment: Firstly i didn't use any code for navigation bar hide or visible .It automatically hide ,not fully hide when i press on hide navigation bar space then it's appear .And also I do not want to sticky bar. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

you can check documentation also : [check here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)

Comment: super.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
,,,


I tried this code but when interrupt another program on this such as messanger , then it didnt work . And one think i want only show the navigation bar not to hide the bar.

Answer (score 0):

in your activity add this code:

```
private int currentApiVersion;

 final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
// This work only for android 4.4+

currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

    // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
    // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
    // show up and won't hide
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

If only hide navigation bar, add only the flags contain navigation

Comment: This code work but i don't want sticky search bar and also not to hide.Just want to show navigation bar without any problem. Please help me.